# How do I know if my new job will not be too fast paced?

Tags: new-job

I've just accepted a new job, which is the same type of job (same technologies) as my current job, but a bigger environment, etc. The job is senior-level (system admin). My current role is senior but the environment is so relaxed and with so little direction and leadership I am not really delivering anything. It's not a fast paced environment.

So my concern is, I am worried that in new job, it may be a bit too fast paced. Especially, being a senior role. The job is right in that it's the same type of job responsibilities, but I feel like my current job has not prepared me for a fast paced environment of constant delivery so I am worried.

Any advice?

Comment: I assume you already had the interviews? Did you get an impression of the culture, the attitudes of your future colleagues, the work life balance etc?

Comment: Yeah I had the interview. The hiring manager did mention that we come to work, have fun and do work, go home, so there was some emphasis on work/life balance. Didn't get an idea on how fast the environment is, but given the size of the company and number of applications, I can imagine it can be fast. Maybe I just need to man up and learn to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to give a definitive answer to. But here are my two cents:

- Each organisation will have its own work culture. To expect that there will be a seamless migration from one job to another is a bit of a stretch.
- There's nothing wrong about not-being-prepared for your new job. Most of the times, organisations do give a leeway for the new entrants. What matters is how fast you adapt.
- With every job you change, there'll be a learning curve. Some would be longer(in case you opt for a change of technology/role), than others. This in no way means that you should not change your job.

My suggestion:

Given that your current organisation provides a very relaxed culture, there's little chance for you to adapt to anything except some organisation providing a more relaxed one. Go for the offer you have and try it out. It might prove to be difficult, but at least you'll learn something new!